# i want to set visibility for the text view

Tags: android, textview, checkedtextview

Hello In my android application i want to set visibility for the text view .
I am having 3 text-views and 3 check-boxes  in application. i want to set visibility of text-views by checking check-boxes, i am using **"setVisibility()"**. it is working also but problem is when i dont check check-box for text-view1 at that time it shows blank and keeps space for text-view one and then it shows text-view2 & 3. I don't want to show this blank space for text-view1. I want to show the text-view from top which i select from check-boxes..
is there any way to do this ??
Thank you.

Comment: you are in right path just textview.setVisibillity(View.GONE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using **View.INVISIBLE**. However, you need to use use **View.GONE** in order to remove that space.

```
yourEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the visibility to INVISIBLE leaves space for the component. Setting the visibility to GONE should remove the space

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE

Answer (score 0):

Initially Set the visibility to Gone in XML,
Use Oncheck Listener & Change the SetVisibility to SetVisibility(Visible).
& You can also change the Visibility by setting the visibility from int Visibility(8) to visibility (0);